# How to combine multiple images into one image using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create an image collage from multiple images, have been able to build up successfully if all the images are in single folder, but the problem is that when the images are in multiple folders , the collage is not making perfectly its only storing the last image in all the position of the collage.

within this make collage function i am just going to create 2x2 collage right now.

```
def makecollage(image):
    collage = Image.new("RGBA", (5000,2500), color=(255,255,255,255))
    max = 8
    l = list(range(0, max))  
    random.shuffle(l)
    c=0
    for i in range(0,1000,500):
        for j in range(0,1000,500):
      
            photo = image.resize((500,500))        
            collage.paste(photo, (i,j))
            print(i,j)
            c+=1
# Make a directory to save the collage image 
    collage.save("collage"+str(i+j)+".png")
```

through the randomfile() I am been able to pick any random file inside in the sub directories, each sub directory contains only one file right now.

```
def randomFile(directory):
    files_list = os.listdir(directory)
    random_num = random.choice(files_list)
    img_1=Image.open((os.path.join(directory,random_num))).convert("RGBA")
    if img_1 is not None:
        images.append(img_1)
    files_list.remove(random_num)
    makecollage(img_1)

for x in directories[1:]:
    randomFile(x)
```

So the collage works perfectly when all the images are in single folder

[image]

but when images are in multiple sub folders it repeats the last image in all position of collage
[image]

Answer (score -2):

#you should place all the images in a row + column
#and call the function like:

```
import cv2
import NumPy as np

def stackImages(scale, imgArray):
rows = len(imgArray)
cols = len(imgArray[0])
rowsAvailable = isinstance(imgArray[0], list)
width = imgArray[0][0].shape[1]
height = imgArray[0][0].shape[0]
if rowsAvailable:
    for x in range(0, rows):
        for y in range(0, cols):
            if imgArray[x][y].shape[:2] == imgArray[0][0].shape[:2]:
                imgArray[x][y]=cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y],(0,0),None,scale,scale)
            else:
                imgArray[x][y] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y], (imgArray[0] 
 [0].shape[1], imgArray[0][0].shape[0]),
                                            None, scale, scale)
            if len(imgArray[x][y].shape) == 2: imgArray[x][y] = 
  cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x][y], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    imageBlank = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
    hor = [imageBlank] * rows
    hor_con = [imageBlank] * rows
    for x in range(0, rows):
        hor[x] = np.hstack(imgArray[x])
    ver = np.vstack(hor)
  else:
    for x in range(0, rows):
        if imgArray[x].shape[:2] == imgArray[0].shape[:2]:
            imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x], (0, 0), None, scale, scale)
        else:
            imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x], (imgArray[0].shape[1], 
  imgArray[0].shape[0]), None, scale, scale)
        if len(imgArray[x].shape) == 2: imgArray[x] = 
  cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x],cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    hor = np.hstack(imgArray)
    ver = hor
 return ver
```

###... call the image by cv2

```
img1 = cv2.imread("Name_of_Image.Extention")
imgarray = ([img1, img2], [img3, img4])
stackImage = stackImages(0.3, imgarray)
cv2.imshow("img1", stackImage)
```

Thanks

Comment: the function should be dynamic, taking images from the sub directories and pass it to the collage function , the way you have handled that its inappropriate with the question